# How do you set the focus of a TinyMCE textarea element?

Tags: jquery, focus, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE for a textarea on a page but it doesn't play nice in the tabbing order of the other elements.

I can use the following code to capture when I tab out of the first element:

```
$('#title').live('keypress', function (e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 9) {
       alert('tabbed out');
   }
});
```

How can I set the focus to a TinyMCE editor?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Finally found an answer... use the command:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus',false,'id_of_textarea');
```

For my purposes, 'id_of_texterea' was "description", ie

```
<textarea id="description" ... ></textarea>
```

In the form element that preceded my textarea, I added the execCommand above to the element's "onblur" action.

Comment: for a more realistic approach, you could bind that execCommand to a tab keypress on the preceding form element.

Answer (score 37):

I know this is an old post, but just to add my input about having the editor open and focus not working.  What I found that worked for me was this:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus();
```

I had to set this in a window.setTimeout event because of how I was using JS objects and such.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked nicely for me:

setTimeout("try{tinymce.activeEditor.focus()}catch(e){}", 2000);

Comment: After going down through all the previous answer, this is the one that made it all worth it. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Focusing also works like this:

```
tinyMCE.get('id_of_textarea').focus()
```

Check out the tabfocus plugin, that's doing exactly what you want:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/tab_focus.php

Answer (score 13):

```
tinyMCE.get('Description').getBody().focus();
```

The above works in Firefox, Chrome and IE as well. I have not tested in other browsers.

###### Added:

Note: The string `Description` is the ID *(without the `#` !)* for the textarea element that has the `tinymce` class (that is, the textarea element used to anchor the TinyMCE editor).

23-Oct-15: Confirmed to work with TinyMCE 4.1.9 (2015-03-10)

Comment: Not sure why, but the accepted answer did not work for me, whereas this one did.

Comment: Only answer working for me, when thereare more than one instance of TinyMce on the page.

Comment: For me, this is what worked, though I also had to add `tinyMCE.get('Description').getBody().scrollIntoView()` to ensure it was on screen as well.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using tinymce with JQuery.  The following will work

```
$("#id_of_textarea").tinymce().focus();
```

You can only do this after the editor has initialized though and so you may need to wait on one of its initialization events.

Answer (score 11):

**Looks like for TinyMCE 4 a few of these solutions no longer work.**

// Doesn't seem to work on TinyMCE 4

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus',false,'id_of_textarea');
```

// Didn't work

```
$("id_of_textarea").tinymce().focus();

tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus();
```

**What works for me**

// Works great in Chrome, but not at all in Firefox

```
tinyMCE.init({
    //...
    auto_focus : "id_of_textarea"
});
```

// Add this so Firefox also works

```
init_instance_callback : "customInitInstanceForTinyMce", // property to add into tinyMCE.init()

function customInitInstanceForTinyMce() {
    setTimeout(function () {                         // you may not need the timeout
        tinyMCE.get('Description').focus();
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Im working with tinymce 4.x and this one does work for me:
    tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus',false,'id_of_textarea');
I start this command AFTER all is initialized and editor is visible on screen.

Answer (score 7):

What actually works is setting an option in the `configfile` (or jquery file) This option enables you to auto focus an editor instance. The value of this option should be an editor instance id. The editor instance id is the `id` for the original textarea or `<div>` element that got replaced.

Example of usage of the `auto_focus` option:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    //...
    auto_focus : "elm1"
});
```

Comment: Worked fine here. I've put a condition on my code that checks for existence of "autofocus" attribute on textarea field. If true, auto_focus is set to textarea id, else, auto_focus is set to false.

Answer (score 3):

For Auto focus in tinymce the documentation first example says that - https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#auto_focus

```
tinymce.init({
      selector: '#textarea_id',
      auto_focus: '#textarea_id'
});
```

This works for me in ***TinyMCE Version*** `4.7.6`

Comment: Thanks - this one worked! Just a quick note though that the auto_focus field is just an id, not a selector (it doesn't need the hash).

Comment: The link to the documentation is broken. For version 6 it's [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/editor-important-options/#auto_focus). However, this only works if the element on which you're initialising TinyMCE is visible. I am initialising TinyMCE in the `show.bs.modal` event, and the `auto-focus` option doesn't work there, but if I initialise TinyMCE in the `shown.bs.modal` event it works. The problem is that then you see it being initialised on-screen, which isn't as nice.

Answer (score 2):

This should pass focus to the TinyMCE textarea:

```
$("#id_of_tinyMCE_area").focus();
```

Comment: It seems that there is a lot going on in the background for TinyMCE and this will not work.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (TinyMCE version 4.7.6):

```
tinymce.activeEditor.fire("focus")
```

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE 4.7.4

None of the above worked for me, subscribing to TinyMCEs init event did work:

```
const elTinyMce = tinyMCE.get('your_textarea_id');
// (optional) This is not necessary.
// I do this because I may have multiple tinymce elements on my page
tinyMCE.setActive(elTinyMce);
elTinyMce.on('init', function () {
    // Set the focus
    elTinyMce.focus();
    // (optional) Select the content
    elTinyMce.selection.select(
        elTinyMce.getBody(),
        true
    );
    // (optional) Collapse the selection to start or end of range
    elTinyMce.selection.collapse(false);
});
```

Note: focusing on elements doesn't always work if you have the browsers developer tools open. You may be forcing the focus away from the page because a browser can only have one focus.
This solution for example doesn't work either if you have developer tools open.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work with TinyMCE 4.x by using the following:

`tinymce.EditorManager.get('id_of_editor_instance').focus();`

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function to focus the editor with thinyMCE
This is using jQuery, but would be easy to strip this out and use `document.querySelectorAll()`. Use [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) if you need this in es5.

```
let focusEditor = function(editorContainer) {
  let tinymce;
  if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform)) { return; }
  let id = $('.text-editor', editorContainer.innerHTML).first().attr('id');
  if (tinymce = window.tinyMCE.get(id)) {
    try {
      return tinymce.focus();
    } catch (error) {
      return tinymce.on('init', function() { return this.focus(); });
    }
  } else {
    return $(`#${id}`, editorContainer).focus();
  }
}
```

The editorContainer is any element surrounding the tinyMCE textarea, e.g. a div with id 'text-container' you could call `focusEditor($('#text-container'))` or in React `focusEditor(React.findDOMNode(this))`