# set focus on tinyMCE after submit

Tags: jquery, tinymce, focus

I am using tinyMCE editor. I need to set focus on the tinyMCE text area if jQuery validation fails. I have tried number of methods but all failed to set focus. 
I have tried:

```
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus;
```

I have tries this also :

```
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceFocus', false, 'textarea_id');
```

and also

```
    $("#lCmsContent").tinyMCE().focus();
```

Actually i am using jQuery validation, so i need to set focus if the validation fails in case of text editor. For this my code is as follows:

```
        $('.form_validation_cmspage').validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                errorClass: 'error',
                validClass: 'valid',
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').addClass("f_error");
                },
                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').removeClass("f_error");
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').append(error);
                },
                rules: {
                    'vCmsTitle'     : { required        : true},
                    'lCmsContent'       : { required        : true},
                    'status'            : { required        : true}
                }, messages: {
                    'vTitle'        : { required:   "This field is required!"},
                    'lCmsContent'       : { required        : "Description is required!"},
                    'status'            : { required:  'Status field is requerid!' }
                },ignore: ':hidden:not(.chzn_a)',
                invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                    if (errors) {
                        if(validator.errorList[0].message == 'Description is required!')
                        {
                            tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceFocus', false, 'lCmsContent');
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

For text editor:

```
<textarea id="lCmsContent" name="lCmsContent"></textarea>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: why you left `id` param blank `tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus',false,'id_of_textarea');` ?

Comment: @MohitArora Yes i forgot to mention it here, i added the above. but this did not work

Comment: Is there any other way out

Comment: did you try any from these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212552/how-do-you-set-the-focus-of-a-tinymce-textarea-element

Comment: yeaaa :) Thanks @MohitArora, tinyMCE.get('Description').getBody().focus(); this one worked for me

Comment: This was the last answer and i did not try it earlier

Comment: great at least that worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#your_texbox_id").focus();
```

**UPDATE:**

I assume that "activeEditor" is a variable of tinymce initialization.
This should work:

```
activeEditor.execCommand('mceFocus',false,'id_of_textarea');
```

Comment: I have tried this also but this is not helping. I am also checking the firenug, there is no issue in the console also :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case just set `auto_focus: '#textarea_id'` worked.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#textarea_id',
    auto_focus: '#textarea_id'
});
```

In TinyMce Documentation also - https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#auto_focus