# tinyMCE - Manually trigger blur event

Tags: tinymce, blur

I'm trying to manually trigger the tinyMCE editor ***blur*** event.

One can manually trigger the ***focus*** event by `tiny.activeEditor.execCommand('mceFocus')` (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2692058/2342414)), but I can't find a way to trigger the ***blur*** event.

I'll appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you find a solution after these 10 months?

Comment: @Devck-DC I wish I had. please answer the question if you find a solution for it. Thanks!